# How to check if datagrid row is empty?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid that's populated by a MySQL table. The issue here is I've added to it a SelectionChanged event.

```
private void RegistrationDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // if the datagrid has an index value of 0 and above
        if (RegistrationDataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            // Exception gets thrown here
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)RegistrationDataGrid.SelectedItems[0];

            // if the column Tag of the selected row in the datagrid is not empty
            if (row["Tag"] != null)
            {
                //put the content of the cell into a textbox called tag
                tag.Text = Convert.ToString(row["Tag"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is meant to capture the value of a cell in a specific column of the selected row. This works fine.

The problem arises if you select the last row, the one that's always there. The empty one at the bottom with nothing inside it.

> An Invalid cast Exception gets thrown: "Unable to cast object of type
>   'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView"

My assumption is that it's got to do with the fact that the selected row is empty.
 I just need to find a way to get the event to ignore this row when ever it's selected. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid explicit casting if you're not sure wether it will actually perform successfully. I'd have used this:

```
var row = RegistrationDataGrid.SelectedItems[0];
DataRowView castedRow = RegistrationDataGrid.SelectedItems[0] as DataRowView;

if (castedRow != null && castedRow ["Tag"] != null) <------ DONT skip on checking castedRow for null, jumping directly to indexed access.
{
     //put the content of the cell into a textbox called tag
     tag.Text = Convert.ToString(castedRow["Tag"]);
}
```

Comment: Genius! Much appreciated. Advice noted.

Comment: you're welcome. You could have used a check with "is" too, but that would be redundant since you'd be working with the casted result anyway. using "as" is just more convenient with less overhead

Answer (score 2):

You should use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` function to validate the content of that cell, prior to any use of it. Also, before that add another validation to make sure that `row!=null` and `castedRow!=null`.

Regarding your description of "empty last row" - this might be an "add new row" template: check for the `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property (set it to false if you don't use it, so that last "empty row" will disappear).

The final code with Exception handling may look like the follows:

```
private void RegistrationDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView _drv;
    try 
    {
        _drv = RegistrationDataGrid.SelectedItems[0] as DataRowView;
        if (_drv != null && _drv ["Tag"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(_drv ["Tag"]) ) 
        {
            tag.Text = Convert.ToString(_drv["Tag"]);
        }
        else{tag.Text=String.Empty;}
    }
    catch{tag.Text=String.Empty;}
    finally{_drv=null;}
```

}

Hope this will help. Regards,

Comment: I get your point. The problem is the exception gets thrown at the "row" declaration... "row!=null" would have to be placed after that.

Comment: Does it work for ANY row with regular data (not an empty one, as per your case)?

Comment: Yep. It works with pretty much any row I've thrown at it as long as it's got data